# Array matching for headers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

when i upload file, i need to compare two array first one is my state array ;

```
this.state: { 'initArray: ['Name', 'Phone Number'] }
mapping: {}
```

and when i upload file my headers like ;

```
headers : ['name', 'phone_number']
```

i want to compare this two and get similar ones to put mapping object and mapping object should be ;

```
mapping : { phoneNumber: 'Phone Number'};
```

it should be name , value like above.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `const newArray = this.state.initValues.map(value => value.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_'));
    const commonValues = newArray.filter(nA => headers.map(header => header === nA)); 
` and i try to write to mapping this elements.  I m trying also at the moment . @ScottSauyet

Comment: Note that you can edit the question (using the "edit" link right below the tags) to improve the question itself, including this code you've tried.

Comment: I'm confused by your expected mapping object.  Where does `phoneNumber` (the key) come from?  And why isn't `name` mapped since they differ in case?  I think a more complete explanation might help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Scoot . I did it with function to convert camelCase and titleCase . it works .

Comment: Best practices on StackOverflow would then be to add an answer showing what you did.  This site is not a help forum but a place to collect useful questions *and answers*.